# Hide thrown exception messages on Android

Tags: android, exception

Is there a way to block the displaying of thrown exception messages (with all the stacktrace and everything) for an android app ?

**EDIT**:

Well, I know I can use try/catch block to do that that's not what I want.
Is there like a way to specify that in mafinest file or maybe in project settigs or smthng ?

Comment: Write whole code in `try{...}catch(Exception e){}`

Answer (score 2):

you can wrap your code in `try catch`

```
try {
    // code that might throw an exception
} catch (Exception e) {
    //don't print the exception
}
```

Comment: thanks but that's not what I want. Just edited my post